# How to create a video from svg files using a pipe with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to create a video from svg graphics stored in a database. My procedure would be the following to archive that:

1. connect to database
2. create ffmpeg command which takes a pipe as input
3. spawn the ffmpeg child process
4. Wait for the output of the process.

start another thread:
For all svg files do:

1. download the svg from the database into a byte buffer
2. write the byte buffer to stdin of the ffmpeg child process

When running my code I encounter a problem when piping the svg files to ffmpeg.

I used `ffmpeg -f image2pipe -c:v svg -i - -c:v libx264 -y Downloads/out.mp4`. But then ffmpeg gives me the following error:

```
[image2pipe @ 0x562ebd74c300] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: svg (librsvg), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

I found out that there's a `svg_pipe` format in ffmpeg, so I tried that - without success, same error.

Another possibility would be to download all the svg files to a temp directory and then using ffmpeg without a pipe which worked when I tried it. The command would be like this: `ffmpeg -i *.svg -c:v libx264 out.mp4` But in my case I would like to avoid this.

Why does the non piped command work and the piped command (like: `cat sample.svg | ffmpeg -f svg_pipe -i - -c:v libx264 out.mp4` ) fail? And how can I use a pipe in my case?

**My Current Solution:**
I use the `-f rawvideo` argument to pipe my graphics to ffmpeg. That's a working solution but it presupposes that I need to convert the svg graphics into raw RGB format.
I took this solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51909991/4113763) on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

With some trial and error I managed to find a set of arguments that work:

`cat sample.svg | ffmpeg -f svg_pipe -frame_size 1000000000 -video_size 100x100 -i - -c:v libx264 -y out.mp4`

---

We may get the options of `svg_pipe` demuxer by executing the following command:
`ffmpeg -h demuxer=svg_pipe`

Output:

> Demuxer svg_pipe [piped svg sequence]:
> svg demuxer AVOptions:
> -frame_size                .D......... force frame size in bytes (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
> -framerate         <video_rate> .D......... set the video framerate (default "25")
> -pixel_format           .D......... set video pixel format
> -video_size        <image_size> .D......... set video size
> -loop                  .D......... force loop over input file sequence (default false)

For some reason we have to set `-frame_size` argument to be larger than the size of the input file.

---

Note that H.264 codec doesn't support transparency, so in most cases the output is going to look strange (the default background color is black).
Consider overlaying the SVG on white background.

---

Example (using FFmpeg version n4.3.1 in Ubuntu 18.04):

Input:
https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/atom.svg

Output:
[image]